# Run a thread on infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm kinda new to python and I have a code that runs a sound alarm using a thread. How can I run this thread on **infinite loop**?

```
if args["alarm"] != "":
    t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
    args=(args["alarm"],))
    t.deamon = True
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you delete the line `t.deamon = True` you will not need the `while True` in the main function since according to docs -

> daemon¶
>   A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon = False.